# Combining id_tokens and access_tokens for new auth spec

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, openid-connect, jwt

A common misuse of OAuth2 is as a strict authentication protocol.  OpenID Connect addresses this by extending OAuth2 to include an `id_token`.  Implementing clients for OAuth2 and OpenID Connect is a monster project.  The fact that `access_token` is opaque makes it non-interoperable between implementations.  Additionally, implementing proper OAuth2 and OpenID Connect clients and servers is very difficult to get right.

As an exercise, I was dreaming up a new spec.  I was thinking of having a single JWT (we'll call it `auth_token` for now) that acts as an OAuth `access_token`, but contains user data similar to an OpenID Connect `id_token`.  The `aud` claim would include both the `client_id` and the `resource server`, so it can be read by both parties.  Any sensitive data that needed to be encrypted could go in some `encrypted_data` claim (ie the entire JWT will not be encrypted, only the data in that claim).  The new spec would offer similar grant types to OAuth2 to create this `auth_token`.

Hopefully, this would accomplish both delegated authorization and authentication while also introducing interoperability by introducing some standard claims for user data, ala `id_token`.  Obviously, a LOT more thought would need to go into this to make it a real spec.  What are the drawbacks to this general design?